# How to send a lot of POST request in JSON format through JMeter?

Tags: json, post, jmeter

So I have this huge file of json requests that I need to send to an API through POST, they are about 4000 different requests. I tried the CSV method and reference the JSON_FILE in code but it didn't work due to a timeout error, I think 4000 files is just too much for this method

I *could* create 4000 thread groups, each one with it's individual json request but that would be a huge manual labor

Is there anyway to automatize this process?

The json looks basically like this

```
{
    "u_id": "00",
    "u_operation": "Address",
    "u_service": "Fiber",
    "u_characteristic": 2,
    "u_name": "Address #1"
},
{
    "u_id": "01",
    "u_operation": "Address",
    "u_service": "TV",
    "u_characteristic": 2,
    "u_name": "Address #2"
}
```

All the way up to 4000

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What is the anticipated usage of the API endpoint? If it's supposed to process 4000 files at once and it doesn't - this sounds like a bug or a [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) and you need to report it.

If you have a large file with 4000 objects like this:

```
{
  "u_id": "00",
  "u_operation": "Address",
  "u_service": "Fiber",
  "u_characteristic": 2,
  "u_name": "Address #1"
}
```

and want to send them one by one with arbitrary number of users/iterations - you can play the following trick

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the setUp Thread Group
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def entries = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(new File('/path/to/your/large/file.json'))

   entries.eachWithIndex { entry, index ->
       props.put('entry_' + (index + 1), new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(entry).toPrettyString())
   }
   ```

it will create 4000 JMeter Properties like `entry_1`, `entry_2`, each one holding one entry from your large file:

[image]

Then in the main Thread Group you will be able to use [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) and [__counter()](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-counter) functions combination so each user would take the next "entry" on each iteration like:

```
${__P(entry_${__counter(FALSE,)},)}
```

[image]

Comment: Tried this but couldn't get it to work, the JSR223 gives me this response:

JMeterVariables:
JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=true
JMeterThread.pack=org.apache.jmeter.threads.SamplePackage@54e63f6b
START.HMS=152347
START.MS=1663179827601
START.YMD=20220914
TESTSTART.MS=1663179844629
__jm__setUp Thread Group__idx=0
__jmv_SAME_USER=true

Instead of making each entry a separate "entry_N"